# Google Analytics realtime is showing inaccurate source after 7 minutes

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-ads

We are using Google Ads and facebook Ads to promote our website and using Google analytics (GA) to track.
We created a test FB ad like link to our website, i.e., having FB like UTM params in the link.

( ?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=Paid&utm_campaign=Test )

When we did a test with 10 users all coming by clicking that link, GA is showing 10 users in realtime reports. We further checked the source of those users, it properly showed as "Facebook / Paid". 
However, after 7 mins realtime shows the same user's source as "direct" instead of "Facebook / Paid".

Can someone help me understand why GA is treating those users in realtime as "Direct" after sometime.

Note: I haven't changed any code related to session timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real time report does not give accurate information, especially for the source and medium. It is a known fact so there is no solution. You have to wait for the data to appear in the actual report.

**From documentation**

[...] As a result, you'll see traffic and conversions incorrectly attributed to a Source of (direct). You'll only see this in Real-Time reports; in standard reports, traffic and conversions will be attributed correctly

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en&ref_topic=1638563

Comment: Thank you. We are also getting correct source data in conversion reports. We didn't know that realtime source is a generic problem. It would be great if you can link me a source to support your statement

Comment: I improved my answer with reference.